# Unable to find Jupyter notebook via Docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, windows-10

I am very new to docker and Jupyter notebook. I pulled the image from docker, it was able to direct me to the relevant Jupyter notebook. Problem is, whatever plots I am making in the notebook, I am not able to find the file in the system. A file with the name settings.cmnd should be made on my system. I am using Windows 10 home version. I am using the following command

```
docker run -it -v "//c/Users/AB/project":"//c/program files/Docker Toolbox" -p 8888:8888/tcp CONTAINER NAME
```

It is running fine as I am able to access the jupyter notebook but the file is still missing on my system.
Here the folder in which I want to save file is project

Kindly help.

Comment: You're mounting `/c/Users/AB/project` in your host to `/c/program files/Docker Toolbox` inside your container. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: kindly tell me how to proceed then

Comment: I can't since you didn't specify what image you're trying to use.

Comment: The image is electronioncollider/pythiatutorial

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an image called `electronioncollider/pythiatutorial`, so I'm assuming you meant `electronioncollider/pythia-eic-tutorial`.

Default working directory for that image is `/code` so the command on Windows should look like:

```
docker run --rm -v //c/Users/AB/project://code -p 8888:8888 electronioncollider/pythia-eic-tutorial:latest
```

Working dierctory [can be changed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir) with `-w`, so the following should work as well:

```
docker run --rm -w //whatever -v //c/Users/AB/project://whatever -p 8888:8888 electronioncollider/pythia-eic-tutorial:latest
```

Edit:

`electronioncollider/pythia-eic-tutorial:latest` image has only one version - one that is meant to run on linux/amd64. This means it's meant to run on 64-bit Linux installed on a computer with Intel or AMD processor.

You're not running it on Windows, but on a Linux VM that runs on your Windows host. Docker can access `C:\Users\AB\project`, because it's mounted inside the VM as `c/Users/AB/project` (although most likely it's actuall `C:\Users` that's mounted as `/c/Users`). Therein lies the problem - Windows and Linux permission models are incompatible, so the Windows directory is mounted with fixed permissions that allows all Linux users access. Docker then mounts that directory inside the container with the same permissions. Unfortunately Jupyter wants some of the files it creates to have a very specific set of permissions (for security reasons). Since the permissions are fixed to a specific value, Jupyter cannot change them and breaks.

There are two possible solutions

- Get inside whatever VM the Docker is running inside, change directory to one  not mounted from Windows, and run the container from there using the command from the tutorial/README:

```sh
docker run --rm -u `id -u $USER` -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD -p 8888:8888 electronioncollider/pythia-eic-tutorial:latest
```

and the files will appear in the directory that the command is run from.

- Use the modified image I created:

```sh
docker run --rm -v //c/Users/AB/project://code -p 8888:8888 forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial:latest
```

You can find the image on Docker Hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial). The source code is available on GitHub [here](https://www.github.com/Forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial).

Edit:

Due to changes in my version of the image the proper command for it would be:

```
docker run -it --rm -v //c/Users/AB/project://code --entrypoint rivet forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial
```

I release a new version, so if you run `docker pull forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial:latest`, you'll be able to use both the command above, as well as:

```
docker run -it --rm -v //c/Users/AB/project://code forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial rivet
```

That being said I did not receive any permission errors while testing either the old or the new versions of the image.

I hope you understand that due to how Docker Toolbox works, you won't be able to use aliases the way the [tutorial](https://indico.bnl.gov/event/9153/sessions/3929/attachments/29969/46769/slides.pdf) says you would on Linux.

For one thing, you'll only have access to files inside directory `C:\Users\AB\project`, for another file path inside the container will be different than outside the container, eg. file `C:\Users\AB\project\notebooks\pythiaRivet.ipynb` will be available inside the container as `/code/notebooks/pythiaRivet.ipynb`

Note on asking questions:
You've got banned from asking questions, because your questions are low quality. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking any more.

Comment: By using /code, it works, it made a folder and some relevant files. However, Jupyter notebook is showing a kernel error, because of that I am not able to plot my graphs. Kindly give me advice on that one too. It says failed to start the Kernal

Comment: See my edit for an explanation and possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Now it is working smoothly

Comment: I know that it's too much to ask but I encounter the following problem in using one of the jupyter notebooks. I am asking a notebook called Rivet, used for analyzing the particle data. I am accessing the rivet from the windows terminal using the following command: $ >alias rivet= 'docker run --rm -v "//c/Users/AB/project"://code forinil/pythia-eic-tutorial rivet'  this command is supposed to start rivet, following the two more commands. But it shows permission denied. Kindly help me in this too, there is no source for windows10 in the net. I will include the source given for Linux

Comment: $> alias rivet= 'docker run -i --rm -u `id -u $USER`: `id -g` \ -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD <image name> rivet'

Comment: Please accept my answer to this question and open a new one, detailing your new problem.

Comment: Include (in the new question) a link to the tutorial you're using (I'm guessing it's this one: https://indico.bnl.gov/event/9153/sessions/3929/attachments/29969/46769/slides.pdf)

Comment: Stackoverflow blocked my account for 3 days for asking questions. So, I am unable to post the question before 3 days. Yes, I am using the tutorial you mentioned.

Comment: I added some more data to my answer.